# Analyzing a string of characters

Tags: java

I have a string of characters "AAABBB" that I need to parse into a character array in java. I then need to test for "As" and "Bs" only.  I can use the following code to work most of the time but when there is a letter that is not an "A" or "B" it may still return true.

```
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        boolean L1 = false;

        for (char ch: line.toCharArray()){
        ch = L1Stack.peek();
        if (ch == 'A'){
            a.append(L1Stack.pop());
        }
        if (ch =='B'){
            b.append(L1Stack.pop());
        }
    }
    if(a.length() == b.length()){
        L1 = true;
    }
    return L1;
}
```

When it reads a line like "ABCBA" it still returns true.

I added this statement

```
if(ch !='A' || ch !='B')
            break;
```

but then it makes them all false.

Comment: What is `L1Stack` and why don't you just use the `char`s from the line? And why do you use `StringBuilder`s to do the jobs of `int`s?

Comment: why overwriting `ch` inside for loop.

Comment: so should i move ch = L1Stack.peek(); outside of for loop? Wouldn't ch stay the same then, since it would only peek once.

Comment: L1Stack is a stack I filled with the letters from the string "AAABBB".

Comment: Also, we were not allowed to count the letters, that is why I didn't use int s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you expected

```
    StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    boolean L1 = false;

    for (char ch: line.toCharArray()){
    ch = L1Stack.peek();
    if (ch == 'A'){
        a.append(L1Stack.pop());
    }
    else if (ch =='B'){
        b.append(L1Stack.pop());
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
if(a.length() == b.length()){
    L1 = true;
}
return L1;
}
```

I have changed the the this part:

```
else if (ch =='B'){
    b.append(L1Stack.pop());
} else {
   return false;
}
```

If not A and not B is in the string the function returns `false`

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU. I have been staring at this for hours! It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I do not whether using stack was mandatory, yet you could accomplish this in easier way like this
Code:

```
   String s = "AAAACCCAAABBBBBCCAAAACA";
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        String[] sToArray = s.split("");
        for (String sIndex : sToArray) {
            switch (sIndex) {
                case "A":
                    result.append("A ");
                    break;
                case "B":
                    result.append("B ");
                    break;
                default:
                    continue;
            }
        }

        for (String v : result.toString().split(" ")) {
            System.out.print(v);
        }
```

output:

```
AAAAAAABBBBBAAAAA
```

Comment: Based on the OP's previous question, I *think* the stack was necessary

Comment: k sound great but it is good to show other ways as well. do not you agree?

Comment: I certainly don't disagree.

Comment: The purpose is to get a boolean value, not a string output, so this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use less memory and objects, if you won't be needing the As and Bs:

```
int checker = 0;
for (char ch: line.toCharArray()){
    ch = L1Stack.peek();
    if (ch == 'A'){
        L1Stack.pop();
        checker++;
    }
    if (ch =='B'){
        L1Stack.pop();
        checker--;
    }
}
if(checker == 0){
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: I think this would be considered counting and we are not allowed to do that

Comment: I would not call it counting since you decrease the count and reach any count of any variable.